# eBay Fees forecast

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I'm looking for an Excel formula that could help me forecast the price I need to list the item in order to make an 20% NET profit from all products.

**The data I have is**:

1. eBay & paypal fees.

(e.g: ebay fee is 7% off sellig price + $0.3

paypal fee is 2.9% off sellig price + $0.2)

1. product cost.
2. shipping cost.

***SO***: if the product cost $50 and lets say the shipping is free then I need to list the product for $66.78 in order to make a NET profit of 20% = $10. (ebay fee: $4.54 | paypal fee: $2.24)

How can I use a formula to forecast the "$66.78" cell?

**Some helpful links**:

1. [eBay.com Fees for eBay Stores](http://pages.ebay.com/help/sell/storefees.html)
2. [eBay Fees Calculator.](http://www.rolbe.com/ebay.htm)

Best Regards,
Tomer S.

Comment: What have you tried? You can't really expect people to go to ebay, check the fee schedule and create the formula for you...

Comment: I just can't find the mathematic formula to do so. the Excel fees are VERY simple to apply.
let's say: shipping is $5
ebay fees: 10% + $0.30 (10% off the selling price)
paypal fees: 3.9% + $0.20 (3.9% off the selling price)

Comment: Found a solution!

By using the Goal Seek tool on Excel.
good tutorial video: http://mistupid.com/viewlets/excel/xlgoalseek.htm



Good Luck!

Comment: OK. One very BIG problem. You have to do this manually, one by one.
Quite a problem when you have 2000 rows!!!

Comment: Once again, you should edit your question and make it more specific, maybe with a simple example and you sould get answers.

Comment: edited the question. Is that more like what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you have given, you have:

```
Revenue = Selling Price x (1 - % Fees) - Flat Fees - Shipping
Profit = Revenue - Cost
```

And you also want:

```
Prodit = 20% x Cost
```

So you need:

```
Selling Price = (1.2 x Cost + Flat Fees + Shipping) / (1 - % Fees)
```

So in Excel, you can use the following (lines 12 and following are just a check):

[image: Ebay & Paypal fees calculation]

By the way, the answer to your example is $67.15, not $66.78.

Comment: Wonderful! can you please answer me one last question?
what if the fee for ebay is 7% for $0-$50 and 5% for $50+?

Comment: That's a bit tricky. A good approximation would be to replace the value in B2 with a formula: `=IF(B1*(1+B8)>50,0.05,0.07)` but it might not work if the selling price is very close to 50.

Comment: Ohh... What I ment was if the final value price is $60 then you calc the first $50 * 0.07 and $10 * 0.05.
VERY sorry if i wasn't clear.

Comment: Mmmm. Not that easy. I'll give it a try a bit later

Comment: Thank you, I realy appreciate it!

Comment: A good enough approximation would be to put this formula in B2: `=IF(B1*(1+B5+5%+B4)>50,0.05,0.07)` and this formula in B3: `=IF(B1*(1+B5+5%+B4)>50,1.3,0.3)`. It will give you a margin slightly higher than 20% for products that cost between $37 and $39 (up to 20.1%), but it will work fine otherwise.

Comment: You should also revise the formula in B12 which will be slightly off for numbers between $37 and $39 too.